# jQuery delay remove element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of buttons used to copy content to the clipboard (using clipboard.js). When one of these buttons is clicked, I am using jQuery to create an element next to it which expands out to let the user know it has successfully been copied to the clipboard. 
I have this functionality working but i am trying to remove the element once it has come in and gone out, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Using `.delay(2000).remove();` does not work as i believe the `.delay()` only works on animations. giving the element a class and using `setTimeout()` does work, but when multiple buttons are clicked, it removes all elements at the same time which should not happen - they should all appear for 2 seconds then go off.

This is the main code - The buttons are created with js which is why `.live()` is used. I am not sure what is missing in the snippet I've provided, but it works on my localhost (creating the element and animating it) - The element needs to be removed after it has animated out.
(using Bootstrap for styling)

```js
$(function() {
  new Clipboard('.btn-copy');
  
  $('button.btn-copy').live('click', function() {
    $(this).after($('<span/>').css({
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'transform': 'translate(-100%, -7px)',
        'width': '0',
        'color': '#fff',
        'background-color': '#5cb85c',
        'border': '1px solid #4cae4c',
        'border-radius': '4px',
        'padding': '7px 0px',
        'vertical-align': 'middle',
        '-webkit-user-select': 'none',
        '-moz-user-select': 'none',
        '-ms-user-select': 'none',
        'user-select': 'none'
      }).text('Link copied to clipboard').animate({
        'width': '180',
        'padding': '7px 12px'
      }, 200).delay(1000).animate({
        'width': '0',
        'padding': '7px 0px'
      }, 200)
      // .delay(2000).remove() // Remove <span/> element here
    );
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border: 1px solid #4cae4c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1...</td>
    <td>
      <button data-clipboard-text="..." class="btn-copy btn btn-success">Copy</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2...</td>
    <td>
      <button data-clipboard-text="..." class="btn-copy btn btn-success">Copy</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3...</td>
    <td>
      <button data-clipboard-text="..." class="btn-copy btn btn-success">Copy</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it within the animation success callback and provide delay using [`setTimeOut()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method. Although it's better to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for binding event handler since it's deprecated in jQuery version 1.7.

```
.animate({
  'width': '0',
  'padding': '7px 0px'
}, 200, function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $ele.remove();
  }, 2000)
})
```

```js
$(function() {
  // new Clipboard('.btn-copy');
  $('button.btn-copy').on('click', function() {
    var $ele = $('<span/>').css({
      'overflow': 'hidden',
      'position': 'absolute',
      'transform': 'translate(-100%, -7px)',
      'width': '0',
      'color': '#fff',
      'background-color': '#5cb85c',
      'border': '1px solid #4cae4c',
      'border-radius': '4px',
      'padding': '7px 0px',
      'vertical-align': 'middle',
      '-webkit-user-select': 'none',
      '-moz-user-select': 'none',
      '-ms-user-select': 'none',
      'user-select': 'none'
    }).text('Link copied to clipboard');
    $(this).after(
      $ele
      .animate({
        'width': '180',
        'padding': '7px 12px'
      }, 200)
      .delay(1000)
      .animate({
        'width': '0',
        'padding': '7px 0px'
      }, 200, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $ele.remove();
        }, 2000)
      })
      .delay(2000)
      //   .remove() // Remove <span/> element here
    );
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border: 1px solid #4cae4c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1...</td>
    <td>
      <button data-clipboard-text="..." class="btn-copy btn btn-success">Copy</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2...</td>
    <td>
      <button data-clipboard-text="..." class="btn-copy btn btn-success">Copy</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3...</td>
    <td>
      <button data-clipboard-text="..." class="btn-copy btn btn-success">Copy</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just a friendly depreciation reminder, better to use on() rather than live()

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but wouldn't `$ele.remove()` in this context remove the *button* rather than the animated element?

Comment: @Pranav This is great, Thank you!
By using the animation callback function it makes the `setTimeout()` unneeded, as putting `$ele.remove()` in the callback function triggers it straight after the animation.

Comment: @PranavCBalan using `.on()` doesn't work whereas `.live()` does - any idea why this could be?

Comment: @Jon : maybe you are using older jQuery version(`< 1.7`)

Comment: @Jon : are you sure...?  I think there is multiple versions of jQuery in your page

Comment: @PranavCBalan Ah yes - had it referenced in a php includes file which came after jQuery v3.1.1. Removed it and all is working as desired now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    new Clipboard('.btn-copy');
    $(document).on('click', 'button.btn-copy', function(){
        var elem = btn.after($('<span/>').css({
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'position':'absolute',
            'transform':'translate(-100%, -7px)',
            'width': '0',
            'color':'#fff',
            'background-color':'#5cb85c',
            'border':'1px solid #4cae4c',
            'border-radius': '4px',
            'padding': '7px 0px',
            'vertical-align': 'middle',
            '-webkit-user-select': 'none',
               '-moz-user-select': 'none',
                '-ms-user-select': 'none',
                    'user-select': 'none'
        })
        .text('Link copied to clipboard')
        .animate({'width':'180', 'padding':'7px 12px'}, 200, function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                elem.animate({'width':'0', 'padding':'7px 0px'}, 200, function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        elem.animate({'width':'0', 'padding':'7px 0px'}, 200);
                    }, 1000);
                })
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
 });
```